# condition in htaccess with number of trailing slashes

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The structure of url can be varied :

```
/page/mnu/id/
/page/mnu/submnu/id/subid/
/page/mnu/submnu/submnusub/id/subid/subidsub/
```

need to change

```
page?mnu=$1&id=$2
page?mnu=$1&submnu=$2&id=$3&subid=$4
page?mnu=$1&submnu=$2&submnusub=$3&id=$4&subid=$5&subidsub=$6
```

What I did

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*?)/(.*?)$ page.php?$mnu=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$ page.php?mnu=$1&submnu=$2&id=$3&subid=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$ page.php?mnu=$1&submnu=$2&submnusub=$3&id=$4&subid=$5&subidsub=$6 [L]
```

Here first rules overrides last two rules

while echoing `$_GET` in `page.php`, it is working as expected cause matched with first rule.

```
/page/home/1/

Array ( [$mnu] => home [id] => 1 )
```

But in case of second rule

```
/page/news/national/2/1
```

it prints

```
Array ( [$mnu] => news [id] => national/2/1 )
```

If first rule is deleted, then it prints (which is expected)

```
Array ( [$mnu] => home [submnu] => national [id] => 2 [subid] => 1)
```

same with third rule, it echo

```
/page/news/national/Local/Crime/2/1/1

Array ( [$mnu] => news [id] => national/Local/Crime/2/1/1)
```

If beginning two rules deleted, then it print

```
Array ( [$mnu] => home [submnu] => national [submnusub] => Local [id] => 2 [subid] => 1 [subidsub] => 1)
```

Here how to apply condition if there is only two trailing slash, only four trailing slash, only six trailing slash, so it doesn't override each other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use these rules:

```
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?$nm=$1&mnu=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?nm=$1&subnm=$2&mnu=$3&submnu=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ page.php?nm=$1&subnm=$2&subnmsub=$3&mnu=$4&submnu=$5&submnusub=$6 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Note use of `[^/]+` which means match 1 or more of any character that is not `/`, On the other hand `.*?` will match 0 or more of any character.
Also note `/?$` makes trailing slash optional for each URI scheme.